# In uwp, when navigate from one page to another page, it will flicker

Tags: uwp

In UWP project, when `Navigate` from one `Page` to another `Page`, it will flicker. In the switching moment, I can see `a white blank page flicker`. How to solve this issue?

E.g. `Page A` with Blue background, `Page B` with Red background, or either `Page` with a different background picture. When Navigate, a flicker will occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try disabling page transition animation.

```cs
MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageA), null, new SuppressNavigationTranslationInfo());
```

By default, UWP will have a connection animation when the page is switched. The fade in and out will give you a white screen illusion, but this is normal.

Best regards.